# Initialize a String from a range of Characters in Swift

Tags: swift, string, unicode, range, character

In our code, we found a bug from not writing the alphabet correctly. Instead of `"0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`, we had `"0123456789abcdefghijklmnoqprstuvwxyz"`. So we are wondering if it's possible to avoid similar typo by declaring Strings made from ranges of characters?

Using Swift 4.1+, we tried:

#### attempt 1

```
let 1: String = "0"..."9" + "a"..."z"
```

> Adjacent operators are in non-associative precedence group 'RangeFormationPrecedence'

#### attempt 2

```
let 2: String = ("0"..."9") + ("a"..."z")
```

> Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to two '`ClosedRange<String>`' operands

#### attempt 3

```
let 3: String = String("0"..."9") + String("a"..."z")
```

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'String' with an argument list of type '`(ClosedRange<String>)`'

#### attempt 4

```
let 4: String = (Character("0")...Character("9")) + (Character("a")...Character("z"))
```

> Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to two '`ClosedRange<Character>`' operands

#### attempt 5

```
let 5: String = String(Character("0")...Character("9")) + String(Character("a")...Character("z"))
```

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'String' with an argument list of type '`(ClosedRange<Character>)`'

Comment: I bet you could use the [String.unicodeScalars](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1539070-unicodescalars), similar to what the user "simons" answered in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31739844/swift-2-separating-an-array-into-a-dictionary-with-keys-from-a-to-z/31771283#31771283

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/39982335/2976878

Comment: @Hamish Thanks. I guess that your descriptive fatal error is a better approach than my force unwrap.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`"a"..."z"` is a `ClosedRange`, but not a `CountableClosedRange`. 
It represents all strings `s` for which `"a" <= s <= "z"`
according to the Unicode standard. That are not just the 26 lowercase letters from the english alphabet but many more, such as "ä", "è", "ô".
(Compare also
[ClosedInterval<String> to [String] in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38325735/closedintervalstring-to-string-in-swift/38327096#38327096).)

In particular, `"a"..."z"` is not a `Sequence`, and that is why 
`String("a"..."z")` does not work.

What you can do is to create ranges of Unicode scalar values
which are (`UInt32`) numbers (using the [`UInt32(_ v: Unicode.Scalar)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/uint32/2905770-init) initializer):

```
let letters = UInt32("a") ... UInt32("z")
let digits = UInt32("0") ... UInt32("9")
```

and then create a string with all Unicode scalar values in those
(countable!) ranges:

```
let string = String(String.UnicodeScalarView(letters.compactMap(UnicodeScalar.init)))
    + String(String.UnicodeScalarView(digits.compactMap(UnicodeScalar.init)))

print(string) // abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
```

(For Swift before 4.1, replace `compactMap` by `flatMap`.)

This works also for non-ASCII characters. Example:

```
let greekLetters = UInt32("α") ... UInt32("ω")
let greekAlphabet = String(String.UnicodeScalarView(greekLetters.compactMap(UnicodeScalar.init)))
print(greekAlphabet) // αβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρςστυφχψω
```

Comment: `UInt32` has an Unicode.Scalar initializer `init(_ v: Unicode.Scalar)`. So `let letters = UnicodeScalar("a").value ... UnicodeScalar("z").value` can be shortened to  `let letters = UInt32("a")...UInt32("z")`

Comment: @LeoDabus: You are right, will update the code, thanks for the suggestion. – Fun fact: `print(UInt32("a")) // nil` but `print(UInt32("a") as UInt32) // 97`

Answer (score 7):

This isn't necessarily eloquent but it works:

```
let alphas = UInt8(ascii: "a")...UInt8(ascii: "z")
let digits = UInt8(ascii: "0")...UInt8(ascii: "9")

let 6 =
      digits.reduce("") { $0 + String(Character(UnicodeScalar($1))) }
    + alphas.reduce("") { $0 + String(Character(UnicodeScalar($1))) }

print(6) // "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

Big assist from Ole Begemann: https://gist.github.com/ole/d5189f20840c52eb607d5cc531e08874

Comment: Thank you. You may win the price of readability. I wonder how `reduce` compares to `String(String.UnicodeScalarView(alphas.map { UnicodeScalar($0) }))` in terms of performances.

Comment: Why not just map the elements to create an array of characters? `String(digits.map({ Character(UnicodeScalar($0))} ))`

Comment: or `digits.map{String(Character(UnicodeScalar($0)))}.joined()`

Answer (score 4):

Unicode ranges will be supported by `UInt32`. Let's note that
[`UnicodeScalar.init?(_ v: UInt32)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unicode.scalar/2905753-init) will return a non-nil value when:

> v is in the range 0...0xD7FF or 0xE000...0x10FFFF

As that's a pretty easy condition to fulfill, because at most we'll have two ranges to concatenate, we'll force unwrap values with `!` and avoid undefined behavior.

#### To support ranges without an extension

We can do:

```
let alphaRange = ("a" as UnicodeScalar).value...("z" as UnicodeScalar).value
let alpha = String(String.UnicodeScalarView(alphaRange.map { UnicodeScalar($0)! }))
```

#### To support ranges with an extension

If we make UnicodeScalar strideable, we can make the above more concise.

```
extension UnicodeScalar : Strideable {
    public func advanced(by n: Int) -> UnicodeScalar {
        return UnicodeScalar(UInt32(n) + value)!
    }
    public func distance(to other: UnicodeScalar) -> Int {
        return Int(other.value - value)
    }
}
```

And the solution simply becomes:

```
let alpha = String(String.UnicodeScalarView(("a" as UnicodeScalar)..."z"))
```

#### For ASCII ranges only

We can restrict ourselves to `UInt8` and we don't have to force unwrap values anymore, especially with [`UInt8.init(ascii v: Unicode.Scalar)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/uint8/2908225-init):

```
let alphaRange = UInt8(ascii: "a")...UInt8(ascii: "z")
let alpha = String(String.UnicodeScalarView(alphaRange.map { UnicodeScalar($0) }))
```

or:

```
let alphaRange = UInt8(ascii: "a")...UInt8(ascii: "z")
let alpha = String(data: Data(alphaRange), encoding: .utf8)!
```

---

Big thanks to Martin, Mike, jake.lange and Leo Dabus.

Comment: You can also use initialize a Data object from your UInt8 range and create a string from it using utf8 string encoding `String(data: Data(UInt8(ascii: "a")...UInt8(ascii: "z")), encoding: .utf8)`

Comment: @LeoDabus oh nice!

Answer (score 2):

Putting the elements together I ended up with the following solution:

```
extension Unicode.Scalar: Strideable {
    public func advanced(by n: Int) -> Unicode.Scalar {
        let value = self.value.advanced(by: n)
        guard let scalar = Unicode.Scalar(value) else {
            fatalError("Invalid Unicode.Scalar value:" + String(value, radix: 16))
        }
        return scalar
    }
    public func distance(to other: Unicode.Scalar) -> Int {
        return Int(other.value - value)
    }
}
```

---

```
extension Sequence where Element == Unicode.Scalar {
     var string: String { return String(self) }
     var characters: [Character] { return map(Character.init) }
}
```

---

```
extension String {
    init<S: Sequence>(_ sequence: S) where S.Element == Unicode.Scalar {
        self.init(UnicodeScalarView(sequence))
    }
}
```

---

```
("a"..<"z").string  // "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy"
("a"..."z").string  // "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

String("a"..<"z") // "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy"
String("a"..."z") // "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

("a"..<"z").characters  // ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y"] 
("a"..."z").characters // ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
```

---

Expanding on that if you really want to accomplish that syntax you would need to implement the closed range and half open range operators with a custom precedence group higher than `AdditionPrecedence`:

```
precedencegroup RangePrecedence {
    associativity: none
    higherThan: AdditionPrecedence
}
```

---

```
infix operator ..< : RangePrecedence
func ..< (lhs: Unicode.Scalar, rhs: Unicode.Scalar) -> String {
    (lhs..<rhs).string
}
```

---

```
infix operator ... : RangePrecedence
func ... (lhs: Unicode.Scalar, rhs: Unicode.Scalar) -> String {
    (lhs...rhs).string
}
```

---

Usage:

```
let 1 = "0"..."9" + "a"..."z"
print("1", 1)   // 1 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

A side effect would be that now you would need to explicitly set the resulting type if you want `"0"..<"9"` to result in a range:

```
let range: Range<String> = "a" ..< "z"
print("range:", range)   // range: a..<z
```