# Swift - FetchRequest custom sorting (function)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

I was wondering how to sort entities (from CoreData) into specific built up arrays.

Let's say I have the following users added to CoreData:

```
Peter Smith
Emily Hughes
Grace Scott
Peter Brown
Ruby Turner
Chloe Scott
James Simpson
```

Currently, It's sorted alphabetically by it's family name:

```
@FetchRequest(
    entity: User.entity(),
    sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \User.lastname, ascending: true)]
) var users: FetchedResults<User>

// Ends up in (for better representation as JSON):
[
    "Peter Brown",
    "Emily Hughes"
    "Grace Scott"
    "Chloe Scott"
    "James Simpson"
    "Peter Smith"
    "Ruby Turner"
]
```

So far, so good. But I want to sort it on a different way and unfortunately, I did not found any solution on the internet. This is how I want to sort it (first, sorted by family name and second by firstname):

```
{
    "b": ["Peter Brown"],
    "h": ["Emily Hughes"],
    "s": ["Chloe Scott", "Grace Scott", "James Simpson", "Peter Smith"],
    "t": ["Ruby Turner"]
}
```

Does anyone of you have an idea how to do this? Maybe how to use a custom function for sorting data fetched from CoreData?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sort descriptors is an array. Simply add an additional sort descriptor to sort by first name after the family name sort descriptor.

Comment: @Paulw11 Yeah, I already know that. But how to sort them into sub-arrays? Like having all users starting with "a" in "a"-array, all users starting with "m" in a "m"-array and so on...

Comment: Ok, that's not a sorting function. That is processing the retrieved data. That is fairly simple. There are some (old) approaches [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31739844/swift-2-separating-an-array-into-a-dictionary-with-keys-from-a-to-z). You can simplify the code with the dictionary [default value subscript](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2894528-subscript). Your real problem is where will you put this code. IMO you should not use `@FetchRequest`, code data belongs in your model not in the view.

Comment: You have to use `NSFetchedResultsController` if you want `sections`

Comment: @Pinnokkio Is the result you are trying to create a JSON, or an actual Swift data dictionary? Also, do the key-value pairs need to be ordered?

Comment: @Paulw11 What should I use instead if not @FetchRequest?

Comment: @loremipsum What do you exactly mean? I mean, I want to sort users alphabetically (as sections) in a list.

Comment: @George_E Swift data dictionary, yes. I just used json in this example for a better understanding

Answer (score 0):

You could use [OrderedDictionary](https://github.com/apple/swift-collections/blob/main/Documentation/OrderedDictionary.md). It is similar to a regular Swift `Dictionary`, but is ordered instead of being in a 'random' order. This allows you to get the names by a character, whilst also preserving the order of the keys.

Example:

```
import OrderedCollections

...

let names = [
    "Peter Brown",
    "Emily Hughes",
    "Grace Scott",
    "Chloe Scott",
    "James Simpson",
    "Peter Smith",
    "Ruby Turner"
]

let dict = OrderedDictionary<Character, [String]>(grouping: names) { name in
    let lastName = name.split(separator: " ").last!
    return lastName.first!
}

print(dict)
print(dict.keys)

for item in dict {
    print(item.value)
}
```

Prints:

> [B: ["Peter Brown"], H: ["Emily Hughes"], S: ["Grace Scott", "Chloe Scott", "James Simpson", "Peter Smith"], T: ["Ruby Turner"]]

> [B, H, S, T]

> ["Peter Brown"]
> ["Emily Hughes"]
> ["Grace Scott", "Chloe Scott", "James Simpson", "Peter Smith"]
> ["Ruby Turner"]

Answer (score 0):

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

extension User{
    //You need a variable you can access with your section "title" or "name"
    //This defines what you want to find in common
    @objc
    var firstLetterLastName: String{
        lastName?.first?.description ?? ""
    }
}
class UserListViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    //This uses the PersistenceController from the standard Xcode setup
    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.previewAware()
    //This contains your sections and objects/values
    @Published var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<User>?
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        setupController()
    }
    func setupController() {
        do{
            //sectionNameKeyPath is where you tell the controller where to find the variable that you want to group
            fetchedResultsController = try retrieveFetchedController(sortDescriptors: nil, predicate: nil, sectionNameKeyPath: #keyPath(User.firstLetterLastName))
        }catch{
            print(error)
        }
    }
    //I put this here so sample a delete. It works a little different
    func deleteObject(object: User) {
        persistenceController.container.viewContext.delete(object)
        save()
    }
    func addSample()  {
        let newUser = User(context: persistenceController.container.viewContext)
        newUser.firstName  = ["Peter", "Emily", "Grace", "Ruby", "Chloe", "James"].randomElement()!
        newUser.lastName  = ["Smith", "Hughes", "Scott", "Brown", "Turner", "Simpson", "Blue"].randomElement()!
        save()
    }
    func save() {
        do {
            if persistenceController.container.viewContext.hasChanges{
                try persistenceController.container.viewContext.save()
            }else{
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
//Most of the extensions mostly comes from the CoreData Programming Guide
//https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/nsfetchedresultscontroller.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH8-SW1
extension UserListViewModel: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate{
    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        fetchedResultsController = fetchedResultsController
    }
}

//MARK: FetchedResultsController setup
extension UserListViewModel{
    func retrieveFetchedController(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor]?, predicate: NSPredicate?, sectionNameKeyPath: String) throws -> NSFetchedResultsController<User> {
        
        return try initFetchedResultsController(sortDescriptors: sortDescriptors, predicate: predicate, sectionNameKeyPath: sectionNameKeyPath)
    }
    private func initFetchedResultsController(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor]?, predicate: NSPredicate?, sectionNameKeyPath: String) throws -> NSFetchedResultsController<User> {
        fetchedResultsController = getFetchedResultsController(sortDescriptors: sortDescriptors, predicate: predicate, sectionNameKeyPath: sectionNameKeyPath)
        fetchedResultsController!.delegate = self
        do {
            try fetchedResultsController!.performFetch()
            return fetchedResultsController!
            
        } catch {
            print( error)
            throw error
        }
    }
    func getFetchedResultsController(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor]?, predicate: NSPredicate?, sectionNameKeyPath: String) -> NSFetchedResultsController<User> {
        
        return NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: getEntityFetchRequest(sortDescriptors: sortDescriptors, predicate: predicate), managedObjectContext: persistenceController.container.viewContext, sectionNameKeyPath: sectionNameKeyPath, cacheName: nil)
    }
    private func getEntityFetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor]?, predicate: NSPredicate?) -> NSFetchRequest<User>
    {
        
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<User> = User.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.includesPendingChanges = false
        //This part helps with efficiency.
        //Maybe a little lazy loading SwiftUI does not slow down
        //as much with large data sets when I use this setup
        fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20
        if sortDescriptors != nil{
            fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
        }else{
            fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(User.lastName), ascending: true)]
        }
        if predicate != nil{
            fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
        }
        return fetchRequest
    }
}
//Here is a sample View
struct UserListView: View {
    @StateObject var vm: UserListViewModel = UserListViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
        if vm.fetchedResultsController?.sections != nil{
            List{
                ForEach(vm.fetchedResultsController!.sections!.indices){idx in
                    let section = vm.fetchedResultsController!.sections![idx]
                    UserListSectionView(objects: section.objects as? [User] ?? [], sectionName: section.name).environmentObject(vm)
                }
            }.toolbar(content: {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigation, content: {
                    Button(action: {
                        vm.addSample()
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                    })
                })
            })
            
        }else{
            Image(systemName: "empty")
        }
        }
    }
}


struct UserListSectionView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var vm: UserListViewModel
    let objects: [User]
    var sectionName: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Section(header: Text(sectionName), content: {
            ForEach(objects, id: \.self){obj in
                let user = obj as User
                HStack{
                    Text(user.firstName.bound)
                    Text(user.lastName.bound)
                }
                .listRowBackground(Color(UIColor.systemBackground))
                
                
            }.onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
        })
        
    }
    //Here is the difference with deleting.
    //The IndexSet is for the section.objects not all the users
    private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            
            let objs = offsets.map { objects[$0] }
            
            for obj in objs{
                
                vm.deleteObject(object: obj)
            }
        }
    }
}
struct UserListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView{
            UserListView()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To change it to a dictionary you can just reduce it.

```
    let sortedForJson = namesArray.reduce(into: [String:[String]](), {
        let firstLetter = String( $1[ $1.index(after: $1.firstIndex(of: " ")!) ] )
        $0[ firstLetter, default: [String]()].append($1)
        $0[firstLetter] = $0[firstLetter]?.sorted()
    })
```

If you want to sort it for display in the view ie: have section names on a table view, you will need to sort by the section title first. So if you want the first letter of the last name you would keep your sort descriptor and add a second one to the array for the first name, then inform the fetched results controller of the section title.

```
       @FetchRequest(
entity: User.entity(),
sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \User.lastname, ascending: true),NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \User.firstName, ascending: true)]
```

) var users: FetchedResults

see docs for displaying section index title name
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller

In this case you only want the first letter to be the title I think so.

```
     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
          guard let sectionInfo = <#Fetched results controller#>?.sections?[section] else {
          return nil
      }
      return String( sectionInfo.name.first! )
    }
```